# how to serach in range in lists and binary search tree for example find(min,max,list)?

Tags: prolog

please help i need to search in binary search tree and return number of iteration to build the list,my predicate always return false

```
findExamsInRange(R1, R2, T, S, N) :- find(R1, R2, T, S, N), N > 0.

find(R1,R2, nil, [], N).

find(R1, R2, t(V,L,R), S, N) :-
    V >= R1, V =< R2,
    find(R1, R2, L, L, NL),
    find(R1, R2, R, LR, NR),
    append([V|LL], LR, S),
    N is NL+NR+1.

find(R1, R2, t(V,L,R), S, N) :- V < R1, find(R1, R2, R, S, N).

find(R1, R2, t(V,L,R), S, N) :- V > R2, find(R1, R2, L, S, N).
```

how to solve this?
no one can answer, who the smart can solve it?

Comment: And you tried doing what? it looks like you want us to do the work for you, but this isn't how this place works

Comment: no i try but i have errors

Comment: And the errors were? provide them in your question

Comment: findExamsInRange(R1,R2,T,S,N):-find(R1,R2,T,S,N), N>0.
find(R1,R2, nil, [],N).
find(R1,R2, t(V,L,R), S,N) :- V>=R1,V=<R2, find(R1,R2, L, L,NL),find(R1,R2, R, LR,NR),append([V|LL], LR, S), N is NL+NR+1.
find(R1,R2, t(V,L,R), S,N) :- V<R1, find(R1,R2, R, S,N).
find(R1,R2, t(V,L,R), S,N) :- V>R2, find(R1,R2, L, S,N).
i always get false

Comment: put it in your question, not as a comment

Comment: i put it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you correct two small problems (related to `N` in the first clause of your find/5 predicate, and to `LL` in the second), then you have code that can search a binary tree of numbers.

The next step is to modify your tree so it can store numbers together with the course name, i.e. a *key* and a *value* in every node.

Finally, you have to write a predicate that builds a search tree from your input list, and you are done.

I assume that you were explicitly asked to use a binary tree, otherwise it would be much easier to search directly in your input list...

Comment: i spend many hours try to correct the error but i am not find it

Comment: @user3137552 If you spent many hours, you should have attempts to show for it. Add them to your question along with what queries you tried and how they failed and then perhaps you can get more detailed assistance.

Comment: Start testing simple examples.  Your Prolog has a "toplevel" where you can type a query.  Type `find(10,70,nil,List,N).`  Which answer do you expect, which answer do you get?  When you have corrected this, try a more difficult query, like `find(10, 70, t(50, nil, nil), L, N).`  If you have written the code yourself, then you should be able to do this...

Comment: it give my false always why?

Comment: @user3137552 you should be far more concerned about the consequences of plagiarism for you. You can be sure your professors know about SO.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger, that's what I do to find such errors.  When you trace the query `find(10, 70, t(50, nil, nil), L, N).`, then you see, after a few steps, a call like `find(10, 70, nil, nil, NL)`.  This fails, but it should succeed, do you see why?  Also, you compiler probably gave you a warning about LL being a singleton variable (a variable that occurs only once on a clause).  Do not ignore such warnings.

Comment: @jschimpf  i trace this query find(10, 70, t(50, nil, nil), L, N).
it give the following error.
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Comment: Then you are tracing a different program.  Anyway, good luck with it, I have given you enough hints, you will just have to put some effort in.